# App store blank just a white screen. does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, app-store-connect

My app store function only returns a blank, white on featured, search, or any of the icon choices at the bottom except upgrades. when i open https://developer.apple.com/account/

it working fine and show me below screen

[image]

but after login to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com it show blank screen ?

[image]

Comment: Just wait for some time, the App store takes some time to load the site from some days. There is nothing wrong with though please check your internet speed as well.

Comment: waiting from previous 3 hours but nothing work for me. it take me to https://appstoreconnect.apple.com/review_agree and that is blank as well, but there is no any pending agreement.

Comment: @AsadFarooq how u sorted this?

Comment: @SunishaGuptan by clearing cache its automatically resolved.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/722866?login=true @AsadFarooq

Comment: it is sorted. After giving the access to the particular user this blank screen gone.

Comment: @SunishaGuptan what do you mean by giving access to the particular user? Where do you give that access? I'm stuck because I just get the blank screen and can do nothing on this website...